# XNA Rectangle Intersection issues

Tags: c#, xna, intersect

I am fairly new at XNA and I have come across a problem.
I have a button class which I am using for a button on the start screen of the game. I want to make it so that when the mouse clicks on the button, a boolean isClicked is set to true and then you can do whatever you want with the button. However, when I compile the game it seems that I can't just click directly on the button's rectangle(or where it should be) but I have to click either below or above it, which changes each time I run the game.

I have this code for the button class:

```
class cButton
{
    Texture2D texture;
    public Vector2 position;
    public Rectangle rectangle;
    public Rectangle mouseRectangle;
    public Vector2 mousePosition;





    public cButton(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition)
    {
        texture = newTexture;
        position = newPosition;






        rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);
    }

    bool down;
    public bool isClicked;

    public void Update(MouseState mouse, GameTime gameTime)
    {




        mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 1, 1);
        mousePosition = new Vector2(mouse.X, mouse.Y);
        if (mouseRectangle.Intersects(rectangle))
        {    
            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)// if mouse is on button
            {
                isClicked = true;
            }
            else 
            {                   
                isClicked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, color);
    }
}
```

}

And this code in the game 1 class for drawing that button:

```
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.MainMenu:
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Backgrounds/title"), new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), Color.White);
                btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);


                spriteBatch.End(); 
                break;


        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

I was thinking that it might have something to do with the screen resolution that I set for it, the code for that is here:

```
    //Screen Adjustments
    public int screenWidth = 1280, screenHeight = 720; 

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenWidth;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenHeight;
```

Please help, I have no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: Screen resolution changes doesn't affect input from the Mouse in XNA, Touch input does get affected by setting a backbuffer.

Answer (score 1):

[I believe this question ought to help you out. :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712932/2d-xna-game-mouse-clicking)

Basically, you create a point struct, and in the rectangle of the button you call the Contains method. It will tell you if the click is on the button.

Comment: This way works sometimes, but sometimes it does not. For me it works more than the previous method, but it still sometimes does not and gives me the same error as above, I have to click somewhere around the actual texture to get the bool isClicked to equal true. Edit: I've also found that the actual position of the mouse is off a bit each time this happens, maybe it has something to do with that?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what caused the mouse positions to be off?

Comment: I think the mouse position was off maybe due to it's window handle. I added this line of code `Mouse.WindowHandle = Window.Handle;` to my game1.cs and it seems to work now.